# Extract month from date fin oracle

Tags: oracle

Here am trying to extract date to year,quarter and month name but its not working month .i extract  month  but it given as Number only but i need as "APR"

```
 to_char(TRAN_DATE,'YYYY') = '2013'
   to_char(TRAN_DATE,'Q') = '2'
  to_char(TRAN_DATE, 'MON') = '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'MON') as abbreviated_name_of_month from dual;

ABBREVIATED_NAME_OF_MONTH
-------------------------
FEB
```

Check out the Oracle docs on [Datetime Format Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079).